# Объединить два запроса из одной таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql

Несмотря на то, что с легкостью реализовываю сложные запросы к БД, простой запрос завел меня в тупик.

Таблица содержит вопросы и ответы, поле status=0 для отвеченных вопросов и status=1 для не отвеченных. Необходимо извлечь записи, где status=0 и status=1 в одном запросе. Понятное дело, я могу просто сделать два отдельных запроса, однако это непрофессионально и уменьшает производительность. Плиз, помогите.

Comment: where status = 0 or status = 1
?

Comment: да нет, нужно на выходе получить два массива - в одном данные со статусом=0, во втором - со статусом=1

Comment: ну, можно вытащить сразу status = 0 or status = 1 , а потом в коде разбить на 2 массива?

Comment: а я не хочу в коде разбивать - это непродуктивно.

Comment: поскольку результат всегда возвращается в виде таблицы, то все равно придется делать либо 2 запроса, либо сортировать в коде.

Comment: GROUP BY status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть, стоит попробовать такой запрос:

`SELECT * FROM table AS one WHERE status = 0 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM table AS two WHERE status = 1)`

Comment: Ну, наверное, это я и хотел увидеть. Как все просто. Теперь вопрос только в производительности в первом и втором ответе.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table   ORDER BY status";
```

Далее, полученную выборку обрабатываем с размещением в массив, над полученным массивом производим `array_reverse()` и получаем на выходе упорядоченный массив - сначала идут записи со статусом 1, а далее со статусом 0. Причем, записи идут в порядке, начиная от последней и заканчивая самой первой.

Comment: @Expert, а кто меня заминусовал, если приведенный мною код отлично работает и вместо UNION использует только один запрос к БД?

Comment: @Expert ♦♦, см. мой комментарий выше.